# I don't understand why it is taking so long to return and never does

Tags: python

```
import random

def pythonrubyjava():

    gamelist = ["python" , "ruby", "java"]

    userinput = raw_input("python, ruby, or java?:")

    randominput = random.choice(gamelist)
    print randominput

    if userinput not in gamelist:
        print "The game is over"

    elif userinput == randominput:
        print "correct"

    elif userinput == "python" and randominput == "ruby":
        print "WINNER!"
    elif userinput == "ruby" and randominput == "java":
        print "WINNER!"
    elif userinput == "java" and randominput == "python":
        print "WINNER!"
    elif userinput == "python" and randominput == "java":
        print "loser..."
    elif userinput == "ruby" and randominput == "python":
        print "loser..."
    elif userinput == "java" and randominput == "ruby":
        print "loser..."
```

this is what i have so far but it either says executing command and never finishes or doesnt return the right thing.

Comment: It neither executes anything nor returns anything. How are you executing this script?

Comment: "it either says executing command"... what is "it"?

Comment: Did you actually call pythonrubyjava() ?

Comment: Interesting variation on "Rock, Paper, Scissors".

Answer (score 4):

Put a main function and then execute it:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    pythonrubyjava()
```

Comment: This. The problem being that you (OP) does not ever call the method you define. You could also remove the function definition and have all the code simply exist as expressions.